# How to write JSNI for jQuery

Tags: gwt, jsni

I have to check if the bottom of scroll has been hit by the user.

The JavaScript code is:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
        alert("bottom!");
    }
});

`enter code here` // How to write this code in JSNI in GWT? I tried but got no result.
```

I have written the above code in JSNI as follows:

```
/*-{
    $wnd.$(window).scroll(function() {
        console.log("WS"+$wnd.$(window).scrollTop());
        $wnd.alert("hi");
    });
}-*/;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be achieved in normal GWT without any need for native code or jquery.

Some methods that may help

- Window.addWindowScrollHandler
- Window.getScrollTop
- Window.getClientHeight
- Document.get().getClientHeight()

Comment: The event handler is not working correctly and giving wrong values while scrolling at the bottom However it does opposite what i want to do .

Comment: Check with the newly released 2.8.2, it fixes a bug in Chrome related to scroll position.

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace all your uses of `window` with `$wnd` too.

But I agree with Knarf and El Hoss that you should avoid using JSNI nowadays to be future-proof. Either use what GWT already provides, or Elemental 2, or possibly use jQuery through JsInterop rather than JSNI.

Answer (score 0):

you can also make use of GWT jquery wrapper: https://github.com/gwtquery/gwtquery